# VS 2008 C++ object array

Tags: c++, arrays, object

So I have a class Coord which is a screen location (x, y) and a class Grid which should be an array of 13 of these Coords, read in from a text file.
The error I'm bumping against is error C2512: 'Coord' : no appropriate default constructor available    grid.h  26
Although I have two constructors for the Coord.h, I thought it would use the input stream one? Kinda hacking bits and pieces from other sources here and learning at the same time so please excuse me if I'm overlooking something obvious.

Coord.h

```
# pragma once

// class for whole screen positions

#include "DarkGDK.h"
#include <istream>

using std::istream;

class Coord
{
    float cx, cy;

    public:
        Coord(float x, float y) : cx(x), cy(y) {} //set components directly
        Coord(istream& input); //set from input

        float x()
        {
            return cx;
        }
        float y()
        {
            return cy;
        }

        Coord operator+(const Coord& c);
};

Coord::Coord(istream& input)
{
    input >> cx >> cy;
}

Coord Coord::operator+(const Coord& c)
{
    return Coord(cx+c.cx, cy+c.cy);
}
```

Grid.h

```
# pragma once

// class for the grid array

#include "DarkGDK.h"
#include "Coord.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 13;
const char filename[] = "grid.txt";

class Grid
{
    Coord gridpos[N];

    public:
        Grid();
        void FillGrid(); //read-in coord values
};

Grid::Grid()
{
    FillGrid();
}

void Grid::FillGrid()
{
    int i;

    ifstream filein(filename, ios::in); //file for reading

    for(i=0; !filein.eof(); i++)
    {
        filein >> gridpos[i].x >> gridpos[i].y; //read in
        filein.close();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have a big misunderstanding somewhere with how a constructor taking an `istream &` can initialize an object with input. `Coord gridpos[N];` means that before your constructor body is entered, all of those are default-initialized.

Comment: Yes sorry, don't know what I was thinking about to come to the conclusion I did, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous little errors in your code. Here's a version that works with some annotations.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 13;
const char filename[] = "grid.txt";

class Coord
{
    float cx, cy;

    public:
        // Default constructor required to declare array: eg Coord c[23];
        Coord() : cx(0), cy(0)
        {}

        Coord(float x, float y) : cx(x), cy(y) 
        {}
        // You were returning float instead of float& which means you could not update
        float& x()
        {
            return cx;
        }

        float& y()
        {
            return cy;
        }

        Coord Coord::operator+(const Coord& c)
        {
            return Coord(cx+c.cx, cy+c.cy);
        }

        friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Coord& rhs)
        {
            input >> rhs.cx >> rhs.cy;
            return input;
        }
};


class Grid
{
    Coord gridpos[N];

    public:
        Grid()
        {
            FillGrid();
        }

        void FillGrid()
        {
            int i;

            ifstream filein(filename, ios::in); //file for reading

            for(i=0; !filein.eof(); i++)
            {
                filein >> gridpos[i];
            }
               // Close the file after you have finished reading from it
            filein.close();
        }
};


int main()
{
    Grid g;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you Peter (and thank you Chris, think my head was feeling worse for wear at this hour lol).